# ¿What happened to protractor-jasmine 2-fail-whale?

Tags: npm, jasmine, protractor

Both their github and the npm registry returns 404.

https://github.com/radialanalytics/protractor-jasmine2-fail-whale
https://www.npmjs.com/package/protractor-jasmine2-fail-whale

Comment: If someone needs it, I've created a repo that you can use directly in your package.json. https://github.com/ramsito90/protractor-jasmine2-fail-whale

Answer (score 1):

it seems to be deleted by the owner , you should contact radialanalytics [here](https://radialanalytics.com/contact)